# Shortest path with min-sum multiplication and Boltzmann distribution

Tags: algorithms, graphs, reference-request, shortest-path, adjacency-matrix

My professor presented a method to find shortest paths using the min-sum multiplication and Boltzmann distribution.
He multiplies the adjacency matrix many times and takes the $\beta$ of Boltzmann very large to find it.

I cannot understand at all the method from my notes, and I cannot find it in my book (Papadimitriou) or on Google.

He wrote something like:
$A^k_{ij}$ is the number of paths from i to j (and that's ok), and then he put $A_{ij}=e^{-\beta w(i,j)}$. Then he took the $\log$ and he used the minsum product over $A_{ij}$.
Then he told that when $\beta$ is very large, any probability distribution will convert in the path of min length.

Can you give me a link where I can study on? Or can you give me a better idea of this method?

Comment: Do you remember anything else? What is the larger context? Inspecting $A^k$ is a standard way to find shortest paths (in unweighted graphs) *deterministically* so I have no idea where and why you'd need something random.

Comment: The larger context is "possible algorithms to solve shortest path problem", like Dijkstra. He wrote that:
$A^k_{ij}$ is the numbero of paths from i to j (and that's ok), and then he put $A_{ij}=e^{-\beta w(i,j)}$. Then he took the log and used the minsum product over $A_{ij}$. As you can see I added many details in my post.